# How do the spores in "Body Snatchers" replicate?

Tags: body-snatchers

In Finney's book "[The Body Snatchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Body_Snatchers)", we learn that:

- alien spores can evolve into different things including human bodies during being asleep and by this human population can be replaced
- replaced population uses agriculture to grow new spores

Does Finney describe, either give a hint what is the actual source of the spores growing on the field?